# When AWS ElasticBeanstalk scales to another server it seems to make it available before it is ready ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When my Java application is deployed to Tomcat on Elastic-Beanastalk it takes a while (11 minutes) because it has to copy large data files from S3 and unzip them, but that is okay because this is all done in .ebextensions and the instance doesn't report itself ready until that is completed.

However, I have it configured for Autoscaling and it seems that when it decides it needs to start a new instance there is a period before the next instance has fully deployed that Elastic-Beanstalk will direct some application requests to this new server, of course because it is not ready it returns a 503 error.

But surely all calls should only go to the original instance until the second one is ready, has anyone else noticed this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether requests are directed to the new instance or not is decided by the Elastic Load Balancer (ELB). Your autoscaled instances are behind the ELB and ELB performs periodic health checks on your EC2 instances to decide whether traffic to your instances or not. By default the health check is TCP connect on port 80. So if ELB can establish a connection to port 80 on the Tomcat server, it will start sending traffic to the instance even before it is actually "ready".

The solution is to use a custom HTTP health check instead of the default TCP check. Set up your web app to return a 200 OK on a special path say '/health_ping'.  Then configure the "Application Healthcheck URL" option to "/health_ping". You can do this using the following ebextension.

Create a file called `.ebextensions/01-health-check.config` in your app source with the following contents. Then deploy it to your environment.

```
option_settings:
   - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application
     option_name: Application Healthcheck URL
     value: /health_ping
```

Read more about this option setting [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html).

You can also configure this in the web console or using the aws cli.

Comment: Thanks for explaining now understand, one small point I set the health check url in .ebextensions as described but when I deployed via web console and got to the page where you canm enter the health check url it was blank, I was expecting it to be filled in by the value in the war. So if I leave it blank will get it filed in at deploytime or not.

Comment: If you do it via ebextensions it will take a short while until the application version is fully deployed for it to show in the console. Also if you have at some point set the health check URL to blank using the web console then setting it in the ebextensions will have no affect. The settings of the API (which is what the web console) uses will take priority over ebextensions. In this case you can set /health_ping using the web console. You can also use the AWS CLI to set this option setting. AWS CLI or console settings will override the ebextensions.

Comment: I think Im missing something I am using ebextensions but deploying the war using website, and I think the healthcheckurl comes up before it has even looked at the war file.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I'm saying that when you deploy via web there is a field to put the health check url, this is never filled in with the value in the .ebextensions files in the war so I don't see how the value in .ebextensaions file will ever be used if deploying via Amazon Management console webpage.

Comment: When deploying using web console if you save a value in a form then Beanstalk will use the value saved in the form rather than your ebextension in case there is a conflict. If you do not save a value in the form then ebextensions will be used. In case of Application HealthCheck URL since the value is part of the launch wizard this value will be used and ebextension could be ignored. You can also use the "aws cli" to update environment. Values set via console/aws cli override the values specified in ebextension option settings.